# Local instance of Amazon Neptune or alternative

Tags: amazon-web-services

I think the answer is no, but I was wondering if there is a way to set up a local instance of [Amazon Neptune](https://aws.amazon.com/neptune/). One of my clients is migrating to Amazon Neptune and I would like to develop locally. Alternatively, it might be good enough to set up a local environment that uses the same languages for loading and querying data.

[Blurb](https://aws.amazon.com/nosql/graph/)

> Neptune supports the popular graph query languages Apache TinkerPop
>   Gremlin and W3C’s SPARQL, allowing you to easily build queries that
>   efficiently navigate highly connected datasets.

Comment: You would probably get better information if you contacted Amazon.

Comment: You might be better off developing against Neptune on AWS than using something else with a similar interface. At 10c per hour it's not too expensive, though of course you pay for data transfer and storage. It's free during the trial period. It might be possible to turn your instance off when you're not using it to save money.

Comment: I am certain you are correct. I spend a lot of time traveling in internet light areas so I was looking for an alternative.

Answer (score 4):

In case anybody is interested, here are the two responses AWS sent over.

> The option of having a local copy for Neptune was discussed yesterday
>   and one suggestion was to look at the open source solution and then
>   migrate (some Neptune features may be different). I understand that
>   this is not addressing your concern, but the good part was that the
>   product team has acknowledged your use case and will look into it.
>
> The white-listing of your access will happen based on the schedule
>   followed by the team. Let me check with the team and get back to you
>   about the preview access. I do not have an ETA for now.

The final message was

> Currently you may not install a copy of Amazon Neptune locally.